# What rules in the C++ and C standards make initialization of static objects from other static objects valid in C++ but not C

Tags: c++, c, initialization, language-lawyer, storage-duration

Why does the code below compile as C++ without complaint, but a C compiler complains that an initializer is not a compile-time constant?

```
int x = 2;
int y = 1;
    
int a[2] = {x, y};

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and  C++ are different languages.  You should not expect code in one language to compile in the other.

Comment: *i tried to look for answer but i didn`t get it.* -- Because there is nothing to look for.  C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: That code doesn't really compile in C++, as you are missing  `#include <cstdio>`.

Comment: C requires initializations to be constants. C++ is more flexible.

Comment: This question is either lacking details on what makes you think that C++ code should compile as C code (still and especially if you add anything with namespaces), or at least what makes you think that this specific code should, or it just is "typo/thinko" to assume that C++ code should compile as C code. I vote to close it for lack of details.

Comment: Why is *Gesellschaft* a valid word in German but not in English?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Adding `#include <cstdio>` would not make the program portable C++ either.  The program currently invokes `::printf()`, which is provided by `#include <stdio.h>`.  Alternatively, a combination of `#include <cstdio>` with `using std::printf;` would also be correct.

Comment: Also notable the current state of affairs with both gcc and clang is a complete mess, they are both non-conforming in this regard. gcc used to be conforming prior to gcc 8 then the gcc maintainers decided to break the compiler. I've brought it up at Bugzilla but speaking to deaf ears. Just assume all initializations like these to be completely non-portable no matter what your compiler happens to say or not say.

Comment: @Lundin Re: "a complete mess": I see the current state of affairs as follows: the C standard permits to "accept other forms of constant expressions". And gcc, clang, and icc do support other forms of constant expressions ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WK6P783oo)). However, the C standard is _silent_ about whether such other forms of constant expressions are required to be accepted _consistently_ across multiple usages (see the demo; indeed, a complete mess).

Answer (score 5):

From the C11 Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
> literals.

In C these declarations

```
int x = 2;
int y = 1;
```

do not provide constant expressions. Even if you will write

```
const int x = 2;
const int y = 1;
```

then again they do not provide compile-time constant expressions allowed to be used as initializers of an object with static storage duration..

From the C11 Standard (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 7 More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers.
> Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the
> following:
>
> — an arithmetic constant expression,
>
> — a null pointer constant,
>
> — an address constant, or
>
> — an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an
> integer constant expression.

and

> 8 An *arithmetic constant expression* shall have arithmetic type and
> shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating
> constants, enumeration constants, character constants, and **sizeof**
> expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall
> only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of
> an operand to a
> **sizeof** operator whose result is an integer constant.

If your compiler supports C23 Standard then you can write

```
constexpr int x = 2;
constexpr int y = 1;

int a[2] = { x, y };
```

In C23 identifier `x` and `y` are called like *named constants* and *named constants* may be used as initializers of objects with static storage duration.

In C++ such an initialization of an object with static storage duration

```
int x = 2;
int y = 1;

int a[2] = { x, y };
```

is called dynamic initialization and occurs at run-time.

Comment: *If your compiler supports C23 Standard then you can write* You also can write until C23: `enum { x = 2, y = 1 }; int a[2] = { x, y };`.

Comment: Just don't forget that "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions". Hence, an `x` defined as `const int x = 2;` (or other) may be interpreted as a constant expression by some implementation. Note: however, per [N2713](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2713.htm) the other forms of constant expressions "are not an integer constant expression".

Comment: Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/WK6P783oo. The C standard is _silent_ about whether such other forms of constant expressions are required to be accepted _consistently_ across multiple usages (see the demo).

Answer (score 1):

In C, static storage duration objects (such as the global variable `a`) must be initialized with constant expressions, which `x` and `y` are not (in either C or C++).

In C++ such objects can be initialized with any expression that they could also be initialized by as automatic storage duration variables. However, for global variables the initialization potentially happens at runtime, usually before `main` is entered, and largely in unspecified order. Therefore non-`constexpr` global variables like this should be generally avoided if possible or special care needs to be taken that dependencies are initialized in the correct order. C doesn't do any dynamic initialization at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
int a[2] = {x, y};
```

Requires runtime code to evaluate the values of `x` and `y`, and running code outside of a function is not allowed in C but is in C++.

Given the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class test {
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    abc() {
        cin >> a;
        cin >> b;
    }
};

test x;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The file scope object `x` has class type with a constructor.  This means that it has to be initialized before `main` is called, and that initialization requires code to run, so this therefore requires a mechanism in place to run code outside of the `main` function.

In contrast, C doesn't have a core need to run code outside of a function, so it was never introduced.  As such, any initialization of static objects in C requires the initializers to be fixed at compile time.

When C++ was created from C, adding the ability to run code outside of `main` became required for the core language to function.